# IntelliJIDEA 13 crashes after OSX update

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, osx-yosemite

I recently updated my OSX to latest Yosemite version and now IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 not starting.

My current Java version:

java version `1.6.0_65`

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

I have checked my `Info.plist` file in `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app/Contents`

```
  <key>JVMVersion</key>
  <string>1.6*</string>
```

It also appears to be fine.

Comment: [This](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks) seems to be relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled java 1.6 from support.apple.com/kb/DL1572 which I have already installed months back. Now IDE is working fine. Didn't do any changes to any environmental variables.